# Custom prefixes don't resolve in BigData triplestore query results

Tags: sparql, triplestore

I am using a BigData triplestore to run SPARQL queries on. The newest version of it (1.3.0) has a number of prefixes coded in it, that resolve in the query results. For example, it has the W3C's 'rdfs:' prefix; whenever a result predicate has its URI, it automatically shortcuts it to 'rdfs:...'. Any older versions don't even have this capability.
Is there a way to make it shortcut custom prefixes (defined by me in the RDF file) in the results?

Apache's Jena has the ability to do this just by taking any prefixes from the query, that would be ideal here too.